# Polymorphism: Passing derived class turns into null?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, conceptual

I have two classes: `ServerOperation` (which is abstract) and `ServerOperationDefinitions` (which is derived from `ServerOperation` and defines abstract functions). I pass `ServerOperationDefinitions` through a function which accepts a `ServerOperation` type, then I pass the argument which is polymorphed into the base class into another function which accepts a `ServerOperation` object. However, when I go to the final destination class and try to call a function, I get a Exception thrown: `System.NullReferenceException`. However, if I manually set the `ServerOperation` object to a new `ServerOperationDefinition`, it works perfectly. What gives?

Here is the first call:

```
 ServerManager.Launch(new ServerOperationDefinitions());
```

Here is the second call:

```
public static void Launch(Object definedServerOperations)
{
    Configuration.ServerVariables.IDENTITY = new UUID();
    SocketManager serverSocket = new SocketManager(Configuration.ServerVariables.PORT, definedServerOperations);
}
```

Final destination

```
public SocketManager(int port, Object operationDefinition)
{ 
    ClientQueueManager queueManager = new ClientQueueManager(this); 
    BeginListen(port);
    opDef = (ServerOperation)operationDefinition;
}
```

Stored as

```
private ServerOperation opDef;
```

Error  here

```
case NetObjectType.CLIENT_SERVER_RESPONSE_GENERIC:
              --->opDef.handleRespondToClient(clientState, recievedNetworkObject);

Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in
```

Edit:
But the error function works if I do this right above it:

```
opDef = new ServerOperationDefinitions();
```

Comment: Any reason why you pass `Object` and not `ServerOperation`?

Comment: I was testing if there was any difference if I switched to object midway through writing this post. They are ServerOperation now.

Comment: Assuming you don't pass `null` to the method, you reach `case NetObjectType.CLIENT_SERVER_RESPONSE_GENERIC` before you initialize `opDef`.

Comment: Well, it looks like a `null` is passed into function for some reason. You could debug it and see what is the value passed to this function...

Comment: Difficult to read, could you give the full code of base class and inherited class?

Comment: Guys. I'm so sorry. I'm an idiot. I just realized I was initializing opDef AFTER I block the thread with BeginListen(); Simply moving opdef before it fixed it. @Guy you were right!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an ordering mistake and lack of sleep.
The thread was blocking opDef from going through. BeginListen blocks the main thread.

Solution:
From this

```
public SocketManager(int port, Object operationDefinition)
{ 
    ClientQueueManager queueManager = new ClientQueueManager(this); 
    BeginListen(port);
    opDef = (ServerOperation)operationDefinition;
}
```

to

```
public SocketManager(int port, ServerOperation operationDefinition)
{
    ClientQueueManager queueManager = new ClientQueueManager(this);
    opDef = operationDefinition;

    BeginListen(port);
}
```

credit to @Guy